# Using 'is' or 'are' in this sentence:

Tags: grammar

Do I need to use 'is' or 'are'?

> Please let me know are there any one or multiple representatives to contact

(OR)

> Please let me know is there any one or multiple representatives to contact

Comment: Better write this way: please let me know whether there are any representatives to contact.

Comment: ***Multiple*** isn't a good word for this context (use ***one or more***). Regarding the singular or plural *verb* form, both are used [about equally often.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+there+one+or+more%2Care+there+one+or+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20there%20one%20or%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20there%20one%20or%20more%3B%2Cc0) Personally I'd *tend* towards plural, but I don't feel that strongly about it either way.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the distinction between one or more than one is important, I would just use *any*:

> Please let me know, **are** there **any** representatives to contact?

The word order, as written, implies you are asking a question. If you meant a request instead, then:

> Please let me know **if there are any** representatives to contact.

Answer (score 0):

As Sina points out in their comment, neither version is really good.

You could go with either:

> Please let me know whether there are...

or

> Please let me know if there are...

As for "any one or multiple", this is a bit much. If you ask if there are *any* representatives to contact, you cover the possibilities of there being 0, 1 or multiple already.

Comment: While "any one or multiple" is a bit much, I'd disagree with using only "any". I'd go with "one or more" if you're unsure how many representatives to contact. Just "any" makes it sound far too vague.

Comment: I'm not sure about it sounding vague, @MrLister. "Are there any cookies left?" is a valid question, even if there may be just one. I can't think of any situation where someone would specify "one or more cookies" just to cover the possibility of there being one left.